# RDS connection with Sequelize is never called in Lambda function

Tags: lambda, aws-lambda, sequelize.js, aws-appsync

I'm using AWS AppSync with Lambda functions as resolvers.
Those functions query an RDS Postgres db (with Sequelize).

**My problem is that whatever I do, none of my queries are triggered. What's wrong with my code?**

```js
import { Context, Callback } from 'aws-lambda';
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: process.env.RDS_NAME,
  username: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
  host: process.env.RDS_HOST,
  port: 5432,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  pool: { idle: 1000, max: 1 }
});

const options = {
  timestamps: false,
  freezeTableName: true
};

const Node = sequelize.define(
  'node',
  {
    nodeId: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    slug: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  },
  options
);

export const getUser = async (
  event: any,
  context: Context,
  callback: Callback
) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  Node.findAll({
    where: {}
  })
    .then(nodes => {
      console.log('nodes', nodes);
      callback(null, {
        id: 1,
        name: JSON.stringify(nodes)
      });
    })
    .catch(err => callback(err));
};
```

I've seen this post but without success.
[Sequelize Code Not Executing Inside AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129781/sequelize-code-not-executing-inside-aws-lambda)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. My RDS was in a different security group than the default one. I had to change it to make it work.